# How to assign int as a key using function dict()?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have started learning python three days ago and I want to assign a number or a integer as my key in dictionary but I am getting an error

```
     a= dict(1=one,2=two)
```

but it is giving me #syntax error:expression cannot contain assignment (pointing at int 1)

but when I do

```
    b=dict(one=1,two=2)
```

It is perfectly working

I know an alternative of using

```
    a={1:'one',2:'two'}
```

but it is too time consuming and I want to know what is error in first one

Comment: What do you mean in "time consuming" in dictionary assignment?

Comment: You can't have a number on the left side of an equals sign. This is the case in pretty much every programming language. In your case you have to use literal syntax with the curly braces.

Comment: Your mentioned alternative is wrong, it must be  a= {1:'one',2:'two'}, without "dict".

Comment: You cannot in the way you want, keyword-arguments *must be valid python identifiers*. You'd have to pass an iterable of pairs, but at that point, you might as well use a literal.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with the `dict` constructor since it receives only valid Python identifiers (numeric values are not).

You can try instead:

```
dict([(1,"one"),(2,"two")])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
a = dict([(1, "one"), (2, "two")])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is logic : assignements only work in one way. 1 = myvar will not work, but myvar = 1 will. Here, you say 1=one... It doesn't work ! But when you reverse it, one = 1, it works. So you found by yourself the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

> a= dict(1=one,2=two)

Such type of dictionary constructors accepts only keys that are valid Python identifiers. One of the rules: an identifier cannot start with a digit.

But you can use another versions of the constructor, e.g.:

```
a = dict([(1, "one"), (2, "two")])
```

Comment: You should define `one` and `two` or pass them as strings.